# Why MyApp widget return error when writing snapshot test using alchemist golden test?

Tags: flutter, golden-test

I have the default codebase configuration in Flutter and I want to write a sample snapshot test for the MyApp widget, inside that widget is a demo for a counter.

This is my code:

`group('GoldenBuilder', () {  goldenTest( 'Counter Snapshot ', fileName: 'tests', builder: () => GoldenTestGroup( scenarioConstraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 600), children: [ GoldenTestScenario( name: 'without color', child: const FancyContainer(), ), GoldenTestScenario( name: 'with black color', child: const FancyContainer(color: Colors.black), ), GoldenTestScenario( name: 'with white color', child: const MyApp(), ), ], ), ); });`

Error will replicate when I add this part
`GoldenTestScenario( name: 'with white color', child: const MyApp(), ),`

I also tried using the statefull widget MyHomePage() then wrapped it in a MaterialApp() but still error occurs.

after running `flutter test --update-goldens`

Hoping someone could help me which part I missed configured.

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aybaq.png)
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPt9o.png)

Tried wrapping in a MaterialApp() and call MyHomePage stateful widget
Tried creating new widget and calling this new widget created is working fine.

It should be success after running `flutter test --update-goldens` and should be added in the red box.

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhXBx.png)